# How can you find out  if sync of an account has turned off?

Tags: android

I have a `SyncAdapter` that extends `AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter`.

I execute a timer task in `onPerformSync` method.

I want to check if the user turned off the Syncing so that I can stop the Timer Task.

I use `ContentResolver.isSyncActive()` method to check this issue.

the problem is that it always returns false.

so how can I check if Sync is turned on/off ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call `ContentResolver.getMasterSyncAutomatically()`.

That will give you the global setting, whereas `getSyncAutomatically` just checks whether an individual Account is enabled and `isSyncActive` simply tells you whether a sync is happening at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

The isSyncActive method just checks if a sync operation is currently running.  You want [getSyncAutomatically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#getSyncAutomatically%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String%29).